# How's the Bash reset in a shortcut by bind not working

Tags: bash, bind

How come the Bash reset in a shortcut e.g. alt-0 in a bind not working

```
bind -x '"\e0":"reset"'
```

it works (gives visible key press echo) only at very first top/time right after screen clearance
then keep on being as invisible echoed keystroke

Any correct solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### tl;dr

```
bind -x '"\e0":reset; stty lnext "" discard "" -icrnl -icanon -echo'
```

---

#### Analysis

I tested in Kubuntu 22.04 LTS.

This is an example output of `stty -a -F /dev/pts/X` when an interactive Bash reads from `/dev/pts/X`:

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 21; columns 188; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = <undef>; discard = <undef>; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig -icanon iexten -echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

This is an example output of `stty -a -F /dev/pts/X` when an interactive Bash reads from `/dev/pts/X` just after your keystroke triggered `reset`:

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 21; columns 188; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

The most important is `icanon`, where it should be `-icanon`. This means just after `reset` triggered by the keystroke the terminal is in the canonical mode, i.e. it doesn't pass characters to the reading program (here: Bash) until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>; or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>).

In the canonical mode you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> and you will see `^[0` (because of the `echo` setting), but Bash will read it (and react to it) only after <kbd>Enter</kbd>. After <kbd>Enter</kbd> Bash will also change the settings to what it expects, so later your <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> will work again (and "break" again).

The settings Bash expects (and imposes, but apparently not directly after `reset` triggered by the keystroke) include `-icanon`. In this mode every keystroke not intercepted by the terminal driver is passed to Bash immediately.

---

#### Solution

You can solve the problem by making the keystroke run not only `reset`, but at least `stty -icanon -echo` after `reset`. There are more differences between the two outputs I posted above; the full fix is in `stty lnext "" discard "" -icrnl -icanon -echo`. So the binding should be:

```
bind -x '"\e0":reset; stty lnext "" discard "" -icrnl -icanon -echo'
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can not reproduce it. Not in Konsole, only partially in gnome-console. Not sure what else to say.